# selecting nested divs under div using javascript/jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to retrieve all the html code under a div element.

My current code is:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tiers/',
        success: function(data) {
             var html = jQuery('<div>').html(data);
              console.log(html);
               console.log(html.find("div#dataTables").html()); //*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"]//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper"]
           //$('#dataTables').html(html.find("div#dataTables").html());

        }
    });
    setInterval("refresh()", 100000);
}
```

Content of the div part:

```
<div id="dataTables">
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid"><div class="table-header">
****<table cell padding=0 ....>****
</div>
```

However, while retrieving the contents of div, we only get the div contents and not the underlying divs

```
<div id="dataTables">
****<table cell padding=0 ....>****
</div>
```

I noticed that we are not able to retrieve the nested div elements using this approach. Please suggest.

Comment: sidenote: Why are you using `setInterval("refresh()", 100000);` inside `refresh()` function? You should look for setTimeout

Comment: Actually he should use setTimout inside the success of the Ajax and .contents

Answer (score 0):

this code will insert the table into every div you have.

```
var html = jQuery('<div>').html(data);
```

i think what you want to do is

```
$('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').html(data);
```

then to get all html inside the first div,

```
$('#dataTables').html();
```

Comment: how do we copy contents of one div to another? Is it like $('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').html=$('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').html(data);

Comment: I would like to copy content of refreshed div into the old div

Comment: it would be $('#div1').html($('#div2').html()) to copy from one div to another.

Comment: $('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper').html(data); gives me the whole page

Comment: I would want to extract div1 from data, and replace the current div1 with the extracted div1

Answer (score 0):

Same as previous answer but faster in javascript

At page load:

```
var element = document.getElementById('DataTables_Table_0_wrapper');
```

To set the html:

```
element.innerHTML=data;
```

To get the html :

```
element.innerHTML=data;
```